# iPhone Objective-C: combining methods together

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json, connection, ibaction

I'm a complete noob at objective-C, so this might be a very silly question to a lot of you.

Currently, I have a view with a 'SignIn' button, which when clicked, activates a sigupUp IBAction that I have defined below. Basically, this method needs to make a JSON call and get back some data about the user.

So, right now, my code looks something like this:

```
-(IBAction)signIn:(id)sender{

//run registration API call

//establish connection
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
 NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[postData length]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease]; 
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.apicallhere.com/api/auth"]]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
 [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Current-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];

[[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
responseData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
}
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response{[responseData setLength:0];}
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{[responseData appendData:data];}
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{/*NSLog(@"%@",error);*/}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{
NSString *response=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
....code carries on from here.
}
```

As you can see, the problem with my code is that even though it is initiated via the 'SignUp' method, it finishes with the 'connectionDidFinishLoading' method. I want to have all this code in a single method. Not 2 separate ones, as I want to be able to return a boolean verifying if the connection was successful or not.

If someone could please tell me how to code up this procedure into a single method, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: please format the code, otherwise, I can not see anything

Comment: *I want to have all this code in a single method. Not 2 separate ones, as I want to be able to return a boolean verifying if the connection was successful or not.*  Actually, you may think you want that, but the first time you get a DNS timeout while trying to sign in, you'll realise you don't want it, nor does anybody else.  It would be much better to maintain some state  in your app so you know how far through you have got with the process.  You can then disable all the controls except "cancel login" until sign in has finished.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want the code all in one method, you're talking about potentially blocking all of the UI and so forth on a synchronous HTTP request method and response call.

The method to put this all "inline" is sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error on NSURLConnection

```
[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:]
```

i.e.

```
NSError *error;
NSURLResponse *response;
[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
... do something with the NSURLResponse to enjoy with your data appropriately...
```

I would personally encourage you to look at an alternative for most of this sort of thing towards the asynchronous methods.

Comment: In your selector name, you're missing a colon, just for clarity. Should be: `sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:` the trailing colon is important. Try and perform the selector without it, and you'll get an error :)